# python regex: extract special substring in a hyperlink

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I use python grabbed a series of hyperlinks,  I want to extract specific character string from these hyperlinks.
the hyperlinks like below:
    “http://tianqi.2345.com/hongkong/61063.htm”

it contains a city name(hongkong) and a city ID(61063), I want to get the result below:

```
cityName=hongkong
cityID = 61063
```

my sample code is below:

```
import re
reNamedGroupTestStr = 'http://tianqi.2345.com/qinxian/61063.htm'
foundTagA = re.search('http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>.+?)/(?P<CityID>.+?).htm", reNamedGroupTestStr);
if(foundTagA):
    GroupCityName = foundTagA.group("CityName");
    print "CityName=",GroupCityName; #I wish to print 'hongkong'
    GroupCityID = foundTagA.group("CityID");
    print "CityID=",GroupCityID;  #I wish to print '61063'
```

but the code throws bug, I am not familiar with regex, can anyone help me?

below is my full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("countyID.html"), "lxml")
#print(soup.prettify())
i = 0
for tag in soup.select('div.bmeta'):
    if i == 5:
        countys = tag
    i = i + 1


for county in countys.find_all('a'):
    countyid = county.get('href')
    print county.get_text()  #Print the city Chinese Name
    print countyid[23:-10] #print the cityName
    print countyid[-9:-4]  #print the cityID
    print '***'
    #break
'''
the sample print result:
***
台北    #Print the city Chinese Name
taipei  #print the cityName
71294  #print the cityID
***
'''

#test regex（ｃｏｒｒｅｃｔｅｄ）
reNamedGroup = 'http://tianqi.2345.com/qinxian/61063.htm'
foundTagA = re.search('http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>\w+?)/(?P<CityID>\d+?).htm', reNamedGroup)
if(foundTagA):
    GroupCityName = foundTagA.group("CityName");
    print "CityName=",GroupCityName; #I wish to print 'hongkong'
    GroupCityID = foundTagA.group("CityID");
    print "CityID=",GroupCityID;  #I wish to print '61063'
```

Comment: You just need to use `'` instead of `"` at the end of the string literal defining the pattern. And escape the `.` in the pattern to match a literal dot. `r'http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>.+?)/(?P<CityID>.+?)\.htm'`

Comment: `.split('/')` is your friend.

Comment: Why are you using  regex?

Comment: It doesn't "throw a bug." It raises an exception that tells you what the error is and where it occurred. You should always include the full traceback in SO questions.

Comment: Also you had this tagged beautifulsoup,  you could do all the filtering directly  using bs4.

Comment: @skrrgwasme  thanks for your reminder

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are the first one to look at my question,thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, but I am afraid the question should be closed as off-topic, since the issue is caused by a mere typo. You could even see it once posted, SO highlighting showed that right away.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, the hyperlinks are grabbed by bs, but I can not use bs to filter text in a hyperlink, do you have idea?

Comment: @dorbodwolf, you can filter all the anchors using bs4and a select statement, there is  no real need to use a regex here at all.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the `"` is a mere typo, but I really do not konw  the regex grammer to splite `.htm`

Comment: @dorbodwolf: Your regex is correct to 99.9%. The named capture groups are good to use although I'd use negated character class `[^/]+` and then `[^/]+?`. The dot will work even if unescaped. The string literal was not well-formed, that is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just split:

```
u = "http://tianqi.2345.com/hongkong/61063.htm"


_, nme, c_id = u.rsplit("/", 2)
print(nme, c_id.split(".", 1)[0])
```

Which will give you:

```
hongkong 61063
```

If you want to check if the url startswith the host:

```
if u.startswith("http://tianqi.2345.com/"):
     _, nme, c_id = u.rstrip(".htm").rsplit("/", 2)
```

Since you are using *BeautifulSoup*, you can filter the anchor tags yourself using the id of the div that contains the links:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://tianqi.2345.com/").content)

for a in soup.select("#hot_l a[href]"):
    print(a.text)
    _, nme, c_id = a["href"].rsplit("/", 2)
    print(nme, c_id.split(".", 1)[0])
```

Output will be like:

```
北京
beijing 54511
```

I cannot add all the output as I am getting a warning about spam but it is all there.

Comment: Yes, I use BeautifulSoup to extract links from the `cityID.html`, and I should better to use only  BS package from begin to end. It is a good habit. And you can adjust your answer, the code area has some mistakes.

Comment: @dorbodwolf, you can use the specific parent elements to get the anchors from, I added a full working example.

Comment: it must be a nice anwser, I have post the full code in the question details.

Comment: I am off my comp for a bit, it is pretty straight forward to get all the info I will edit when I get back on.

Answer (score 1):

Another *alternate* would be to use `urlparse` ([Python2 Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) / [Python3 Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html))

```
# For Python 2
>>> from urlparse import urlparse

# For Python 3
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse

>>> o = urlparse("http://tianqi.2345.com/hongkong/61063.htm")
>>> l = o.path.split("/")
>>> l[1]
'hongkong'
>>> l[2].split(".")[0]
'61063'
```

Comment: I find you have a wrong answer of my question today.

Comment: @dorbodwolf - Wrong!? How so?

Answer (score 0):

You've a simple syntax problem in `search` function, quotes are mismatched (`'` in the start of string and `"` at the end) and if you want to match a dot (`.` symbol in regex matches almost any character), you need to escape it.

```
foundTagA = re.search("http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>.+?)/(?P<CityID>.+?)\.htm", reNamedGroupTestStr)
```

Also, it won't print 'hongkong', it would print 'qinxian'

`;` symbols at the end on lines aren't necessary in python, and it's a bad style to use them

Answer (score 0):

```
foundTagA = re.search('http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>\w+?)/(?P<CityID>\d+?).htm', reNamedGroupTestStr)
```

Above code should work.

Instead of using `.` as wildcard search I use specific `\w` and `\d` to improve efficiency

Answer (score 0):

hope it help.

```
import re
reNamedGroupTestStr = 'http://tianqi.2345.com/hongkong/61063.htm'
# \S matches any non-whitespace character
# \d matches any decimal digit ; equivalent to the set [0-9]
foundTagA = re.search("http://tianqi.2345.com/(?P<CityName>\S+?)/(?P<CityID>\d+?)\.htm", reNamedGroupTestStr);
if(foundTagA):
    GroupCityName = foundTagA.group("CityName");
    print "CityName=",GroupCityName; #hongkong
    GroupCityID = foundTagA.group("CityID");
    print "CityID=",GroupCityID;  #61063
```